# How to fix on loading spring-context?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

What is the possible reason annotation from spring-context cannot be found? I already called spring context on my pom file, but upon calling `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` my eclipse cannot find it.

Any help is much appreciated.
Below is my configuration and how I call it.

[image: pom.xml and dao]

Comment: Please consider **copy/paste your code into your question** instead of using what it seems to be a picture of your screen taken with your smartphone? It's for search engine... Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is definately in that package, try to:

- Right click on project -> Maven -> Update project..
- Project -> Clean

If that does not help.. then remove the project and import it again as a maven project.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maciej Kowalski. It Now workes.